# Why cant convert to UTC from query string

Tags: c#, linq

Working with pgAdmin 4 v6.

I have model with Property "CreatedUTC".
Have a function with one parameter "filter"

```
public async Task<List<MyModel>> GetFilteredData(string filter)
{
   IQueryable query  =  DataContext.MyModels;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
       { 
         query = query.Where(filter);
       }

       var count =  query.CountAsync(); // need for pagination
       // some another actions
       return query.ToList();
}
```

And when I send a query string like `CreatedUTC <= DateTime(\"2022-06-15T04:04:00Z\")` it returns an error with description:

> 'timestamp with time zone' literal cannot be generated for Local DateTime: a UTC DateTime is required

Why it requires time in UTC when I already send It in UTC? If it in local how to convert in UTC?

Comment: Why are you using a string instead of an actual DateTime or DateTimeOffset in the first place? That's a *serious* bug. A `DateTime` is a binary value, not a string. It has no format. If you use EF Core, the generated query will pass it as a parameter, not a string. The code you posted won't even compile anyway - there's no `Queryable.Where` overload that accepts a string

Comment: LINQ doesn't query databases by itself. Which ORM are you using? And where did this `Where(string)` method come from?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  
    `public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> 
      source, string predicate, params object[] args)
        {
            return source.Where(ParsingConfig.Default, predicate, args);
        }
`
 In System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.
And why I dont use simple DateTime because I use blazor library component which can filter data by several parameters which create this query string

Comment: There's no such namespace in EF Core, EF or even the base class library. That's a NuGet package that has *nothing* to do with Microsoft. Someone decided it's a good idea to use `System.Linq` for their package at a time that NuGet didn't block such tricks. `I use blazor library component` I use Blazor WASM too with reporting grids and dynamic filters. I don't filter on the browser though.

Comment: Besides, even that package's landing page uses parameters instead of hard-coded strings. As for your specific problem, you're trying to compare a `DateTime` whose `Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Local` with a field that has a timezone. It's impossible for the server to guess what a client's local offset is, so it refuses to use that value. One option is to use DateTimeOffset, which includes an offset. The other option is to change `DateTime.Kind` to `UTC` or `Unspecified`

Comment: `DateTime(\"2022-06-15T04:04:00Z\")` is *not* a LINQ expression, it's an expression only that third-party library understands. It seems the library calls `DateTime.Parse` without any specifiers, which always returns a `Local` value. If you try `DateTime.Parse("2022-06-15T04:04:00Z").Kind` you'll get `Local`. You'll have to use parameters instead of this string